# Assignment operator in generic class. C++

Tags: c++, templates, generics, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

Hello I have problems trying to overload the assignment operator in my generic linked-queue class.

Here is the code in question:

```
template<typename T> 
class Queue : public IQueue<T>
{
(...)
public: 
    Queue();
    Queue(const Queue<T> &origQueue);
    virtual~Queue();
    Queue& operator=(const Queue<T> &origQueue);
    void enqueue(const T& element);
    T dequeue();
    T peek() const;
    int size() const;

};



template<typename T>
Queue& Queue<T>::operator=(const Queue<T> &origQueue)
{
(...)

    return *this;
}
```

Any ideas of where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Queue<T>& Queue<T>::operator=(const Queue<T> &origQueue)

Comment: `IQueue`'s `operator=` signature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your class is templated, you wanna return a Queue object, so the return value needs to be templated too:

```
template<typename T>
Queue<T>& Queue<T>::operator=(const Queue<T> &origQueue)
//...^
{

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is only required in out-of-class definitions. Inside the class, the name is injected and you can use just `Queue`.